# How to turn off vibration during a factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset, vibration

I am experimenting with my phone quite a lot, and I need to do a factory reset quite often (several times per day).

Everything works fine, but it vibrates several times during the factory reset. *And it's really annoying.* Maybe someone know, how to turn those off - some setting maybe?

<sup>I'm using Android 2.3.6, Alacritous v3 Mod.</sup>

Comment: I would think that is a normal operation for factory reset - it does vibrate to let you know that the reset is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using the menu found under settings when the phone is fully booted.
Doing a factory reset from clockworkmod recovery shouldn't make the phone vibrate. Boot to recovery and choose wipe data/factory reset. The effect is the same as the menu in the settings.

Comment: Yeah, I'd even say you _shouldn't_ reset the device from the regular settings menu, better to do it from CWM as you'll have quick access to ROM installs and all that.